# Reference request - conjugacy classes over local fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, local-fields, conjugacy-classes

Is there a nice reference for reductive groups over local fields, which for example contains discussion of things such as: Given a semisimple element in $G(F)$, its $G(F)$-conjugacy class is closed in the analytic topology of $G(F)$, and related things?

Comment: I don't know such a reference. However, I would suggest to ask a reference for the following assertion: the $G(\overline F)$-conjugacy class of any semisimple element in $G(\overline F)$ is Zariski-closed. The tags in such a question should include invariant-theory.

Comment: Now it remains to show that if $F$ is a local field and $X$ is a homogeneous space of $G$, then the orbits of $G(F)$ in $X(F)$ are closed in the analytical topology. Proof: the number of orbits is finite (see Serre, Galois Cohomology), and they are open, hence the complement of each orbit is open, hence each orbit is closed.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Dear Michael, the first fact I knew, but your next comment helped me understand better how to think about this rational situation. Thank you!

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Do you know if something goes wrong if $F$ has char. p? I think of $G(F)$ etc. as analytic manifolds, so don't have a feeling of what can go wrong in char. p

Comment: Serre (GC, III.4.4, Thm. 5) assumes that $F$ is *perfect* when proving that there are finitely many $G(F)$-orbits in $X(F)$.

Comment: In char 0, since $X$ is homogeneous,  for any $x\in X(F)$ the map $$\phi_x\colon G\to X, \quad g\mapsto g\cdot x$$ is smooth, and hence the map on $F$-points $G(F)\to X(F)$ is open by the implicit function theorem, and hence the $G(F)$-orbit of $x$ is open.

Comment: However, I think that all will work also in char p, if the (scheme-theoretical) stabilizer of $x$ in $G$ is a smooth connected reductive group.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi OK, thank you, I will think about that.

Comment: More generally, if $F$ is a henselian valued field, $X$ a homogeneous space under an algebraic $F$-group $G$, and the stabilizers are smooth, the $G(F)$-orbits are open and closed in $X(F)$. This follows from Proposition 3.4.1 in [this paper](http://content.algebraicgeometry.nl/2014-5/2014-5-025.pdf): note that if $x\in X(F)$ the corresponding orbit map $G\to X$ is a $G_x$-torsor over $X$.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Thank you!